# How can I extract src data which I got by using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, get

```py
import os
import re
import sys
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

path = os.getcwd()
time_st = time.time()

url = "URL"

# Regular expressions
id2 = re.compile("gr\d")
fig = re.compile("fig\d")

html = requests.get(url).text
sp = BS(html, "html.parser")
J_Fig = sp.find_all("figure", {"id": fig})
print(J_Fig)
for Fig in J_Fig:
    print(Fig.get("src"))
```

This is what I've used and I want to get only src address from this code. First, `print(J_Fig)` was working well.

However, there was all codes about figures. So, when I run this code above, output was just "none".

What should I do when I want to get only src data? Thank you.

P.S. I've used `print(Fig['src'])`. It did not work either.

Comment: Hey @박준서  welcome to SO! can you provide URL so it will be better for understanding!

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is unavailable when you do not have account. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: If the link is unavailable, atleast post some of the HTML code of the page so that it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Please provide HTML code/structure if link is not available!

Comment: 'url = "https://h-glacier.tistory.com/entry/Python-%ED%8C%8C%EC%9D%B4%EC%8D%AC-BeautifulSoup4%EB%A5%BC-%EC%9D%B4%EC%9A%A9%ED%95%B4-%EC%9B%B9-%ED%81%AC%EB%A1%A4%EB%A7%81-%EC%98%88%EC%A0%9C-%EB%A7%8C%EB%93%A4%EC%96%B4-%EB%B3%B4%EA%B8%B0"
id2 = re.compile("gr\d")
fig = re.compile("fig\d")
html = requests.get(url).text
sp = BS(html,"html.parser")


J_Fig = sp.find_all("figure",{"class":"imageblock alignCenter"})
print(J_Fig)'
this is example URL and I admitted the class of figures. 
But It did not worked either

Comment: @박준서 comment is not for sharing code! please [edit] your question and highlight what you are trying to extract!

Answer (score 0):

Below is an answer for what in your comments:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x.img['src'] for x in soup.select('.imageblock')]
    pp(goal)


main('https://h-glacier.tistory.com/entry/Python-파이썬-BeautifulSoup4를-이용해-웹-크롤링-예제-만들어-보기')
```

Output:

```
['https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/Lpy7b/btqD6REn6D3/UWaaWCuCBKimtzAHp7lJ71/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/djSmqZ/btqD6lr4aYI/9XXKO277XFN8REnBWKAU80/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/ed2ktw/btqD7Hg6lAo/3n12aVBRPiJUiMMhdCaoG0/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/Mapl1/btqD53yuVe3/Gb7VfyZ1PoKnCSGffkgV2K/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/7Vged/btqD4y6X9dn/92pKptURb0VHu232pYAxqk/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/lwzPC/btqD8hbbIbK/jnedJ6lBgKFxUUMzBytSD0/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/dPJydy/btqD6lyOmpr/PXLYckP40Mvn6JqI1rQsrk/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/begZOh/btqD8inCSyt/dkV15mFKXFeFlpxDCWQA71/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/lLVFC/btqD8iOOeF8/dWfpa68wKNXPUboXgcZbz1/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/bBAlHO/btqD7XKUr8k/gbaOmtBDJS8i9kbIRJKko1/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/dMyQri/btqD5JAm4m6/htHrr9R8R0YDVhZG0rRJd0/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/cskT4k/btqD4x780hK/KTjb7CM7st6As4M43aoMX0/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/do1c5R/btqD6lFFEcH/D5mUX6YQVqEimkeVR7mTnK/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/eg5W5P/btqD4yeW9Tt/ratG7YkUekSQKsaktxisF0/img.png',
 'https://blog.kakaocdn.net/dn/pFxu2/btqD8PyQre4/8IpreDBy0exCHkSTRb8ne1/img.png']
```

And this is an answer for your initial post:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x for x in soup.select('figure[id^=og]')]
    print(goal[0])


main('https://h-glacier.tistory.com/entry/Python-파이썬-BeautifulSoup4를-이용해-웹-크롤링-예제-만들어-보기')
```

> you will not find `src` attribute for that output.